# Tile veneer cabinets / fix veener damage

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, kitchen-counters, backsplash

My wife would like me to put in a tile backsplash for the kitchen.  She really didn't like the granite backer, so I had to pull it off.  Problem is, the granite was glued onto the cabinet, and when I was trying to scrape off the caulking, it obviously did some damage.

Is there any way to fix this damage?  If they were solid cabinets I'd just sand and re-stain, but since they're a thin veneer, not sure if this is possible.  Would I be able to cover it in chalkboard paint, or would it be possible to just tile over the veneer?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can tile on this surface - just like you can tile directly upon primed drywall. All tile needs is a sound surface - wood, drywall, cement, backer board, Denshield, plywood, brick etc.

Comment: Well that's the million dollar question "Is the veneer a 'sound' surface"?  I'm leery that the veneer would peel from the eight of the tiles.